# Better quality way to set a flag outside of a foreach that determines an action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I often find myself needing to iterate through a collection of elements to determine whether one or more of the elements has a particular property at a point in time. In order to determine the behaviour that occurs if the property in question is present, I clear a flag using a boolean and iterate through the collection, setting the flag and then later acting on the flag's value.

Here's an example:

```
function disableButtonIfAnyFailuresVisible() {
        var failureRows = $(this).find(".validation-row-failure");

        anyVisible = false;
        failureRows.each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
                anyVisible = true;
            }
        });

        if (anyVisible) {
            $("#continue-button").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    }
```

Within this method, I want to find all of the `.validation-row-failure` elements on the page, and I want to check if they are visible or not. If there are any visible on the page, I want to prevent the user from proceeding by disabling the continue button.

To do this, I first set the `anyVisible` boolean to false, and I then iterate through each element in my collection, if any of them are visible `anyVisible` is set to true and then the `if(anyVisible)` conditional will fire.

As I mentioned before I use this approach semi-frequently, however I can't help but think that this is a poor way of going about this particular scenario. I'd like to know if there's any other better quality ways I can go about this?

Comment: Have a look at lodash and all its helper functions. Specifically here ‘_.any(...)’. Of course you can write these helpers yourself as well. If you do, it’s more performant to have a standard for-loop in which you can return early

Answer (score 3):

`Array.some()` might be what you are looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Something along these lines should work:

```
let failureRows = $(this).find(".validation-row-failure").toArray();
let anyVisible = failureRows.some(row => row.is(":visible"));
$("#continue-button").prop("disabled", anyVisible);
```

Answer (score 1):

As Markus Dresch mentioned, the [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is a very neat solution, specially designed to check if an element, corresponding to a certain patter, exists in the array.

Just an improvement of your solution - you can break the array loop once you have found a matching element:

```
anyVisible = false;
for(const row of failureRows) {    // change from `.each()` to `for of`
    if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
        anyVisible = true;
        break; // break once match is found
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is fine here's a tighter refactored version. If you want to break out of an `.each()` loop just add `return false` at the end of your `if` statement.

```js
$(".fail").each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
    $("#cont").prop("disabled", true);
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class='fail'>
    <td>FAIL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='fail'>
    <td>FAIL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='fail'>
    <td>FAIL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='fail'>
    <td>FAIL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='fail'>
    <td>FAIL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='fail'>
    <td>FAIL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='fail'>
    <td>FAIL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='fail'>
    <td>FAIL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='fail'>
    <td>FAIL</td>
  </tr>

  <button id='cont'>Continue</button>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```